# Print onClick URL in WKWebView embedded as deep-link in react-native

Tags: ios, react-native, wkwebview, deep-linking, react-native-ios

```
  onNavigationStateChange={(event) => {
          console.log("test",event);
          }
        }
```

I'm trying to detect on click of a hyperlink in WKWebView which method is called? The URL is embedded in a react-native app, and on click navigates to a detailed page within the app.
How can i detect which method is called on click of hyperlink?